# using array input names in forms and form validation - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a form which on submit will send its data to two different tables.So I thought writing like this will help me to deal with the posted data easily.

```
<?=form_input(array('name'=>'item["item_manufacturer"]','class'=>'form-control'),set_value('item["item_manufacturer"]'));?>
<?=form_input(array('name'=>'vat["vat_percentage"]','class'=>'form-control'),set_value('vat["vat_percentage"]'));?>
```

and in `config/form_validation` config file,I have this

```
$config = array(
       'products/add' =>array( array('field'=>'item["item_manufacturer"]','label'=>'lang:manufacturer-name','rules'=>'required|trim|xss_clean'),
                        array('field'=>'vat["vat_percentage"]','label'=>'lang:vat-percentage','rules'=>'required|trim|xss_clean')
));
```

but it comes like `form_validation` result is false even if entered something as inputs.

all I want is to write something like this,

```
$this->db->insert('items',$this->input->post('item'));
$this->db->insert('vats',$this->input->post('vat'));
```

isn't it possible to do something like this? or is there a better way? Hope someone helps

**Solved**

small mistake, changed `'item["item_manufacturer"]'` to `"item[item_manufacturer]"` :)

Comment: Vickel, pls see the updated question.I've added that.

Comment: If the question is solved add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

small mistake, changed `'item["item_manufacturer"]'` to `"item[item_manufacturer]"` :)